# How to selectively display content of a shared component

Tags: angular, components

I have a shared component, which provides content for three other components. I need to add a search filter to two of the three components. I placed the code in the shared components because that's, where the information to be filtered, is rendered. The filtering works fine but the search field is displayed on all the three components. How do I choose to add the search field on only selected components?

In the main component (employee.html)I am using the shared component (list)

```
 <app-list [model]="cards" 
           [emptyMessage]="No Employee"></app-list>
```

In list component. I added the search box and applied the search filter on the for loop that displays the employee name

```
<mat-form-field class="search-field">
<ng-content></ng-content>
<mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
<input autofocus matInput #searchTermInput type="search"
     [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" >
</mat-form-field>
```

//applying search filter

```
<div class="empty-view" *ngIf="model && model.length === 0">
{{ emptyMessage }}</div>

<mat-card *ngFor="let item of model | searchFilter:searchTerm">
```

Search-filter pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Card} from "./card";

@Pipe({
name:'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
transform(model: Card<any>[], searchTerm:string):Card<any>[]
{
if(!model || !searchTerm){
  return model
}
return model.filter(item 
=>item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())!== -1)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a boolean variable as an input on the shared component, then do an ngIf on the variable to display the search if true, then on the parent/presentation component pass false on the input variable for the sections you don't want to display the search and do otherwise for the one you want to show.
That will fix it